# Given a collection of stacks of different heights, how can I select every combination possible?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, stack

**Input:** total cost.

**Output:** all the combinations of levels that give the desired cost.

Every level of each stack costs a different amount (level 1 in stack 1 doesn't cost the same as level 1 in stack 2). I have a function that converts the level to the actual cost based on the base cost (level 1), which I entered manually (hard coded).

I need to find the combination of levels that give me the inputed cost. I realize there are more than one possible solutions, but I only need a way to iterate trough every possibility.

Here is what I need:

input = 224, this is *one* of the solutions:
[image: these are the costs]

---

I'm making a simple program that needs to select levels of different stacks and then calculate the cost, and I need to know every possible cost that exists... Each level of each stack costs a different amount of money, but that is not the problem, the problem is how to select one level for each stack.

I probably explained that very vaguely, so here's a picture (you'll have to excuse my poor drawing skills):

[image: these are the maximum levels]

So, all stacks have the level 0, and level 0 always costs 0 money.

**Additional info:**

- I have an array called "maxLevels", length of that array is the number of stacks, and each element is the number of the highest level in that stack (for example, maxLevels[0] == 2).
- You can iterate from the 1st level because the level 0 doesn't matter at all.
- The selected levels should be saved in an array (name: "currentLevels) that is similar to maxLevels (same length) but, instead of containing the maximum level of a stack, it contains the selected level of a stack (for example: currentLevels[3] == 2).
- I'm programming in C++, but pseudocode is fine as well.
- This **isn't** homework, I'm doing it for fun (it's basically for a game).

Comment: I've re-read the question several times and am struggling to understand it. Could you perhaps provide a concrete example, showing the inputs, the output, and the steps taken to compute the output?

Comment: I don't believe that you'll get anything from that... Only input is the cost, and each level of each stacks adds up a little, so the program's task is to find the exact combo of different levels so it matches the cost. I'll be right back and I'll edit the question!

Comment: `( currentLevels[0] + currentLevels[1] + currentLevels[2] + ... ) == requested_cost` Is this what you want to achieve? Or can the cost of level 5 be different from 5?

Comment: I fail to understand this so I am inclined to vote to close as Not A Real Question. However, then perhaps someone else comes along with an answer. For the love of God, can you please tell us what the **question** is?

Comment: @bane do you ask for algorithm that generates all possible costs, given the current configuration of stacks and the cost of each item in each stack? Or do you ask for algorithm that given one cost value and given configuration of stacks ant the cost of each item will produce the selection of stacks that generates given cost value?

Comment: Here, I described it more thoroughly, I hope that's clear enough! In the essence the algorithm is very simple... I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but here's how to churn through all the possible combinations of selecting one item from each stack (in this case 3*1*2*3*1 = 18 possibilities):

```
void visit_each_combination(size_t *maxLevels, size_t num_of_stacks, Visitor &visitor, std::vector<size_t> &choices_so_far) {
    if (num_of_stacks == 0) {
        visitor.visit(choices_so_far);
    } else {
        for (size_t pos = 0; pos <= maxLevels[0]; ++pos) {
            choices_so_far.push_back(pos);
            visit_each_combination(maxLevels+1, num_of_stacks-1, visitor, choices_so_far);
            choices_so_far.pop_back();
        }
    }
}
```

You can replace `visitor.visit` with whatever you want to do with each combination, to make the code more specific. I've used a vector `choices_so_far` instead of your array `currentLevels`, but it could just as well work with an array.

Comment: Hey, I'm pretty new to C++, can you re-code it in pseudo code? What does size_t mean? What's the is the star and the "&" sign? Something to do with pointers, I presume? I think it can be done simpler... What is "Visitor" anyway? An object? I completely lost myself at "std::vector<size_t> &choices_so_far"... Also: "maxLevels+1", isn't that an array? How can you add 1 to the array?

Comment: Hey, I think I figured it out. In the essence my solution is similar to yours because I used recursion as well, so I accepted your answer because you have me that idea. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is very simple, if I've understood it correctly. The minimum cost is 0, and the maximum cost is just the sum of the heights of the stacks. To achieve any specific cost between these limits, you can start from the left, selecting the maximum level for each stack until your target is achieved, and then select level 0 for the remaining stacks. (You may have to adjust the last non-zero stack if you overshoot the target.)

Comment: No, that isn't the case. The exact cost is a combination of different levels of different stacks. Look at the new picture, please. :)

Comment: Well in that case, your problem is NP-complete, because it reduces to the knapsack problem if the height of each stack is 2. What this means in practice is that you're screwed if the number of stacks gets bigger than about 30 or 40 -- see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-complete.

Comment: I wont have any problems with that. As I said, it's for a game, and it's goal is to calculate which researches some player has. There are 16 researches in the game, therefor I'm using 16 stacks. Each research has a level, and each level costs two times the previous one, and the first one is the base cost of that research. I figured it out, I think, although it's not functioning well (but not this part, I do select every possibility). After I figured it out, I quickly tested it on the #1 player in the world's points and it gave  results in just a few seconds.

Answer (score 2):

I solved it, I think. @Steve Jessop gave me the idea to use recursion.

**Algorithm:**

```
circ(currentStack)
{
    for (i = 0; i <= allStacks[currentStack]; i ++)           
       if (currentStack == lastStack && i == allStacks[currentStack])
           return 0;
       else if (currentStack != lastStack)
           circ(++ currentStack);
}
```